# How to trigger event when a specific div is in visible in client window

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

I have a blog that consists of consecutive entries, ie. divs. I have a separate background image for each entry. I want to change background image when a specific div gets visible in the client window. I couldn't figure out how to trigger it.

I think this is not about :visible or .show, all divs are alredy visible. However the page is long due to consecutive entries and I just want to change background image when the page is scrolled and a div get in sight.

**Note:** A javascript solution would be better by the way, if exists... rather than jQuery

Comment: I believe you should be able to check window height, `$(window).height()`, and then check the position of the entry from the top.

Comment: Just FYI, a jQuery solution is by nature a Javascript solution. :-)

Comment: Your keywords are 'in viewport'. Check out these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229291/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-the-view-of-the-user-with-jquery

Comment: I just want to be sure whether there is a built-in solution or not. I don't want to use jQuery, so I wrote that line :) and thanks for the 'viewport' keyword, I am checking those solutions right now.

Comment: Have a google for mutation events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to bind a function to the windows scroll event and validate the div's when the event is fired.
$j(document).bind("scroll", function() {
  //check here
});

I found where someone is offering a plugin for this sort of thing too: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

--edit--
here is a similar question and answer: 
[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)